# I need help for Python Programming class making

Tags: python, maya

I have written a code which I want to access directly from Maya Script Folder.. 
When Ever I try to access "poly" or "srfc" from the pallete. Its says "name is not defined".
I am new to python programming but want to make a tool like this. Kindly Help in this regards. I even want to wrap all this in a class. Please help in that regards too..

```
import maya.cmds as mc
def win():
    if mc.window("filters", exists = True):
        mc.deleteUI("filters")

    myWindow = mc.window("filters", t= "Tools", s = False, rtf= True, wh = (3, 500))
    mc.rowColumnLayout(nc=20)
    mc.button(l = "mesh", w= 30, h= 18, c = "poly()", bgc = (.3,.3,.3))
    mc.showWindow(myWindow)


def poly():
    currentPanel = mc.getPanel(wf = True)
    if mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, q=True, polymeshes = True) == 1:
        mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, e=True, polymeshes = False)
    elif mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, q=True, polymeshes = True) == 0:
        mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, e=True, polymeshes = True)
```

Comment: Do you use additional code to tell Maya what to execute? If so, can you post that too?

Comment: yes, "win()" is the command I execute. However it shows my window but I cant access my code from the window I made.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `poly()` function as a string. That only works if poly is defined in the same namespace as the code which calls `win()`.  Wrapping both functions in a class will let them see each other:

```
class Tool(object):

     def win(self):
         self.myWindow = mc.window("filters", t= "Tools", s = False, rtf= True, wh = (3, 500))
         mc.rowColumnLayout(nc=20)
         mc.button(l = "mesh", w= 30, h= 18, c = self.poly, bgc = (.3,.3,.3))
         mc.showWindow(self.myWindow)


     def poly(self, ignore):
         # ignore is needed because the button always passes an argument
         currentPanel = mc.getPanel(wf = True)
         if mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, q=True, polymeshes = True) == 1:
              mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, e=True, polymeshes = False)
         elif mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, q=True, polymeshes = True) == 0:
              mc.modelEditor(currentPanel, e=True, polymeshes = True)


t = Tool()
t.win()
```

You also should reference the function object `poly` directly not as a string (note the lack of quotes here)

Here's a [reference on the different ways to hook controls up cleanly](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)

Comment: Thanks for the support but, I did not understand the point clearly. still after wrapping in class its not working.. Error :  # Error: poly() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
# TypeError: poly() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Also let me know if there is any tutorial which can help me understanding classes and definations use in maya.

Comment: sorry, see edit above.  The reference in my answer covers most of what you need to know for hooking up command callbacks, but [tech-artists.org](http://tech-artists.org/) is a good general resource for this too

Comment: Thanks, it works if I run all the script from the script editor and then using the window. But When I am trying to store this script in my script Directory and then importing, reloading and calling the Tool command, its say's its not defined. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Tool will be part of a module if you save it in a file and import it.  You'll just need to add `from modulenamegoeshere import Tool' and then call the last two lines